# gdbserver reports wrong target architecture

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I'm remotely-debugging an **x86_64** executable on **x86_64** target, but **gdbserver** seemingly reports debugging an **i386** executable:

On the **target**:

```
# gdbserver --attach :9999 12345
Attached; pid = 12345
Listening on port 9999
```

On the **host**:

```
# gdb
<normal GDB banner>
(gdb) target remote 10.0.0.1:9999
Remote debugging using 10.0.0.1:9999
0x773660d8 in ?? ()
(gdb) show architecture 
The target architecture is set automatically (currently i386)
```

Is it **gdb** (at the host) or **gdbserver** (at the target), who determines the architecture wrongly? Why could this happen, and how to fix it?

TIA for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

*> Is it gdb (at the host) or gdbserver (at the target), who determines the architecture wrongly?*

It is gdbserver.

*>  Why could this happen?*

I was using a gdbserver binary, built for the wrong architecture (i386).